# simple_html_dom find tbody and other components

Tags: php, html-table, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to deal with it all day but I can't find out how to parse my table items.. I have table:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
           <img title="this is img which I need also" />
         </td>

         <td>
            <div>
                TEXT WHICH I NEED
            <div>
            <div>
                2nd TEXT WHICH I NEED
            <div>
            <div>
                3rd TEXT WHICH I NEED
            <div>
            <div>
                4th TEXT WHICH I NEED
            <div>
            <div>
                HREF which I need
            <div>
            <div>
                TEXT which I need also
            <div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>

</table>
```

so how to get it? this is not 1 table, there is 5 tables at all and this is last one (I got it already `$table = $raw->find('table'); echo $table[4];` ) but how to get all other data? I have stuck there:

```
print_r($table[4]->find('tbody'));
```

it returns me false or nothing..

Comment: Your HTML code isnt well-formated (no closing div tags), is that just a copy paste error or the actual html is like that ?

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your html example unless you'll say it wasnt an error !

Then based on that, we have:

- Only one `img` tag, so we can directly search for it and get the title `$table->find('img',0)->title`
- All the other wanted texts are withing a `div` tag, so we can search for all divs, then, using a loop, print their content

Here's a working code summarizing what said above:

```
$table = '
    <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>
               <img title="this is img which I need also" />
             </td>

             <td>
                <div>
                    TEXT WHICH I NEED
                </div>
                <div>
                    2nd TEXT WHICH I NEED
                </div>
                <div>
                    3rd TEXT WHICH I NEED
                </div>
                <div>
                    4th TEXT WHICH I NEED
                </div>
                <div>
                    HREF which I need
                </div>
                <div>
                    TEXT which I need also
                </div>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>';

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($table);

/////////////////
// Find img title
$imgTitle = $html->find('img',0)->title;

echo "IMG title: </br> $imgTitle </br></br>";

////////////////
// Find all divs
$divs = $html->find('div');

echo "DIV's content:</br>";

// loop through all found divs and print their content
foreach($divs as $i => $div) {

    echo "$i: " . $div->plaintext . "<br>";
}

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
IMG title: 
this is img which I need also
DIV's content:
0: TEXT WHICH I NEED 
1: 2nd TEXT WHICH I NEED 
2: 3rd TEXT WHICH I NEED 
3: 4th TEXT WHICH I NEED 
4: HREF which I need 
5: TEXT which I need also
```

<kbd>[Working DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nu6-m8c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if($emails) {
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

            $message = base64_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1));
            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            $html->load($message);
            $tds = $html->find('td');

            foreach($tds as $i => $td) {

                echo "$i: " . $td->plaintext . "<br>";

            }

    }
} 

imap_close($inbox);
```